# Display posts by a certain user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, controller, dashboard

In my rails app, I need to display on a users 'dashboard' posts in which that user had made.

Dashboard Controller :

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.find(params[:id])||current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @post = Post.all(:order => "created_at DESC")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end

end
```

My Dashboard 'Show View'

```
<div class="dash-well">
    <div class="gravatar-dashboard">
        <%= image_tag avatar_url(@user), :class => 'gravatar-pos-fix gr-dash-mar-top' %>
        <h1 class="nuvo wtxt"><%= @user.username.capitalize %></h1>
        <h3 class="nuvo wtxt"><%= @user.motto %></h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dash-well-status">
<% @post.each do |post| %>
    <div class="post">
      <div class="tstamp">
        <%= image_tag avatar_url_small(post.user), :class => 'gravatar' %>
        <strong>Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago by <%= post.user.username %></strong>
      </div>
      <div class="status"><%= post.status %></div>
    </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

AND My Dashboard Model :

```
class Dashboard < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :status, :author, :email, :username, :id, :user_id, :user, :website, :bio, :skype, :dob, :age

  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :user
end
```

So, does anyone know how I could display only the posts from the users dashboard (The users dashboard is accessible from any user so, current_user wont work!)

Comment: is there any relation between User and Post?

Comment: @SagarBommidi User has_many :posts and Posts belongs_to :user

Comment: I guess your posts have a column `user_id`, why don't you use it instead of `Post.all()`?

Comment: @Gerep What do you mean use it instead of `Post.all()`

Comment: You are getting all posts without checking it the user is the owner, since your posts belongs_to users, you can do `user.posts`, try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @posts = @user.posts

  #.....
end
```

This will display only the posts of that particular user only.

Comment: that displays `undefined method each`

Comment: here in my code, it is **@posts** and in the form it is **@post**. Is this the reason? Check once...

Comment: this @posts is a array so you need to loop it, you can't access it directly

Comment: Sorry, I dont quite understand what that means, i'm pretty new to rails

Comment: How @posts will be a hash? It wont be a hash as i know. When u fetch associated objects like user.posts, this will be either an array or an ActiveRecord Relation object.

Comment: So, how can I loop it or whatever I need to do?

Comment: @coreypizzle: No need to do any thing, your current implementation works fine. If still having problem, let me know what exactly.

Comment: No, as I said it does not display the post.status

Comment: Are you able to see the **username** of that post? If so, then the value for the attribute **status** is nil. To make confirm, replace <%= post.status %> with <%= post.status.blank? ? "None" ? post.status %> and try.

Comment: Are you sure that in your view you're calling the correct var? `@post` or `@posts`? check that in your controller and view

Comment: @SagarBommidi If i do that it just says `unexpected ), expecting :`

Comment: sorry... my mistake. `<%= post.status.blank? ? "None" : post.status %>` try this.

Comment: Are you getting username correctly? and can you inspect the **post** object? like just put <%= post.inspect %>   inside the loop and can u paste the output here, so that we can try to trace whats going wrong.

Comment: OH! This is embarrasing! THE ENTIRE TIME MY COLOR WAS SET TO WHITE! Sorry I'll mark ur answer as right anyways!